# Do I have to wait for ITIN for H4 spouse?

Tags: immigration, taxes, application-status

I hold an H1B visa and my wife just moved to California as an H4 dependent. I have applied for ITIN along with filing my federal taxes.

How do I file my California State taxes? Should I wait for her ITIN and then file my CA taxes or can I file my CA taxes without her ITIN? I was told by the IRS officer that it would take 8 weeks to get the ITIN. In that case, should I file for an extension for filing my California taxes?

This is what I found in the instructions book of from 540. It does not say anything when one doesn't have an [ITIN](https://mollaeilaw.com/blog/itin/).

Comment: Is the ITIN for your spouse? You should have a social security number, in which case you should not have an ITIN.

Comment: @phoog - H4 dependent spouses don't get SSN's. Only the H-1b with work authorization gets an SSN, so the H4 spouse has to get an ITIN to be able to submit as "married filing jointly".

Comment: @brhans I'm aware of that.  But the first paragraph implies that OP has applied for an ITIN for himself, as could the last.